# Methods to protect client-side Chrome extension code

Tags: security, encryption, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on creating a Chrome extension that uses client-side JS to automate a task on a website. Since this tool would be used by businesses, I'm planning to sell it in a subscription-based model. Previously, Chrome had a payments API that could protect someone from having access to the client-side code without first paying, but they've since [deprecated that API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/cws-payments-deprecation/). Additionally, it used to be possible to get remote code and execute it within a Chrome extension, but Chrome has now also [forbade](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#remotely-hosted-code) that. And on top of that, it is [not acceptable to obfuscate code](https://blog.chromium.org/2018/10/trustworthy-chrome-extensions-by-default.html).

Given all of these very strict restrictions, I'm wondering what options we as developers have to enforce any amount of security for our code. Obviously this is client-side code, meaning there is no true way to fully protect it, but what I'm initially thinking is:

1. Minify/bundle the code. Minification is allowed and I've been able to publish bundled/minified extensions before. This helps to hide intent of functions by shortening their names.
2. Use `scripting.injectScript` to inject individual functions from the background script to tabs rather than have it readily available on the page. This hides the logic a bit and makes it a bit harder to track the flow.

Given the above, my main question is about payment status checks. I will have a backend with authentication that integrates with Stripe. I'm wondering if there's some way I can maybe check with my server on a daily basis for paid status, store that status in chrome.storage, and then have checks throughout my code that check chrome.storage without making it stupidly easy for someone to just do `chrome.storage.sync.set({ paid: true })`. My thought to adding just another hurdle at least is to have the server return an encrypted payload containing the id of the user and the time they last authenticated as well as a key to decrypte it. The Chrome extension would then have the ability to decrypt the payload and check that the date and id are accurate. For the user to get around this, they'd have to have some basic encryption understanding and do it on a daily basis, which would hopefully be too annoying to be worth it.

To be clear, I understand that sending the key to the client makes it so that this isn't actually secure, and the user could even go through the code to manually remove the checks, but the goal here is to just make it hard enough that the average user would have a hard time figuring out how to overcome the challenges and it wouldn't be worth it.

Does anyone have any other strategies they're employing or just ideas in general in this new era of Chrome extensions?

The only other option I could think of that would actually secure a Chrome extension but that wouldn't fly by the Chrome team is having the extension code be encrypted at the time of download and the user would need to subscribe to get a key to decrypt it. But this would violate the obfuscation rule. Would be nice if we could talk to the Chrome team about allowing something like that where we could give them a key at time of submission.

Comment: At the current state it seems only Firefox permits the uploading of obfuscated code.
This is true if at the same time you upload a non-obfuscated copy of the code for the audit of the reviewers.
If the review phase will succeed then only the obfuscated copy will be available for the download\installation.

Comment: Chrome really oughtta follow suit. Even better would be allowing the code to be encrypted and the user would need to get a license key to decrypt it after installation.

Comment: Extensions can use WASM. Would that help secure the code?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the application type, whether it's a native binary, a javascript app, JVM or anything else whatever is downloaded by the client side it's going to be susceptible to be inspected – some formats make it harder to be introspected than others but nothing stops clients from reading source code.

- JS files are just text, so they're easiest to introspect of all other formats.
- .jar files contain JVM bytecode and one can also read and make sense of that.
- Same goes for native executables or WASM. One can just read the assembly. And there's no need to run through all the code. Once one has added a "secret token" into the source code it's going to be embedded on the data section of that binary.

So if your plan is to ship the functionality on the client side, people will have ways of getting your algorithms and reverse engineer your code. It's just going to take more or less time.

---

Your best bet is to host a backend service which only you have access to and has control on running these crytical operations. **Essentially not shipping the crytical code**

You may ship a "secret code" (read API token) to users paying for the service and allow X/requests per month and check whether they've exceeded their rate before running the operation on the backend.

This way you authenticate your customers and even if they make a copy of the app, the crytical code is owned by you on your server and they will only be able to do as much as your backend allows them to.

How would you lend an entire motorbike to your friend and make sure he can only turn it on a set amount of times without you watching at him? :)

---

#### Further reading

You might be interested in reading about [white box cryptography](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-white-box-cryptography-ph143u5v) and discovering some techniques that are documented in academic papers. (not listed in that link)

You may also be interested to read this stack exchange answer claiming that – so far – [all white-box cryptographic methods have been broken and proved insecure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/392)